# кто может перевести это с pascal na java прошу помочь

Tags: java, pascal, while

```
var
    a, b, c, i : integer;
begin
    write('a: '); 
    readln(a);
    write('b: '); 
    readln(b);
    if a > b then {если a больше b - меняем местами}
    begin
        c := a;
        a := b;
        b := c;  
    end;
    i := a;
    while (i <= b) do
    begin
        writeln(i * i * i);
        i := i + 1;
    end;       
end
```

Comment: Бюро переводов по другому адресу.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение, но сразу говорю, что больше такого не просите. На этой площадке не решают, а отвечают на вопросы, поэтому правильнее было бы попробовать написать код, а затем, если что-то не получается, уже спросить.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PascalToJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0, b = 0;
        System.out.print("a: ");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            System.out.print("b: ");
            b = 0;
            b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (a > b) {
            a = a + b;
            b = a - b;
            a = a - b;
        }
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            System.out.println(i * i * i);
        }
    }
}
```

И еще, я сделал замену переменных местами по-другому, чтобы не нужно было создавать третью временную переменную.

Answer (score -3):

```
{
        int a, b, c, i;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("a: ");
        a = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("b: ");
        b = reader.nextInt();
        if (a > b) {
            c = a;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }

        i = a;
        while (i <= b) {
            System.out.println(i * i * i);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Кто поставил плюс этому "ответу"?